# Vanishing fields inside custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, customdialog

I've tried to create custom `Dialog` with `ImageView`, 2 x`TextView`s, 3 x`RadioButton`s and 2x`Button`s. Of course I couldn't make it as regular `Dialog` (because of variety of `View`s used), so I've decided to create custom `layout` and a `Class` which would take care of setting it all up. Everything seemed to be fine, until I builded it.
Dialog showed only `ImageView` and first `TextView` but other `View`s were gone.
[image: DialogBox]
Should look like this:
[image]
Thats my code - layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_site_gray">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/igloo_theme_color"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/burgrundy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:text="Akceptuj"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:text="Odrzuć"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:text="Przekaż dalej"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/igloo_theme_color"
        android:text="Anuluj"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton4" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Class:

```
public class DialogCreator extends Dialog {
    public DialogCreator(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void showSwitchDialog(Context context, String taskID, boolean isCoordinator, View.OnClickListener posButtonClickListener){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_switch_service);
        TextView task = dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView chooseOptionText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Button cancelButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button okButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        RadioButton redirect = dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);

        if(!isCoordinator) redirect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(posButtonClickListener);

        task.setText("ID: " + taskID);
        chooseOptionText.setText("Choose option:");
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

Method call (dialog show):

```
DialogCreator dc = new DialogCreator(MainScreenActivity.this);
                dc.showSwitchDialog(MainScreenActivity.this, "000000", true,  new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        RadioButton radioAccept = v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
                        RadioButton radioDecline = v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
                        RadioButton radioRedirect = v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);

                        if(radioAccept.isChecked()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainScreenActivity.this, "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if(radioDecline.isChecked()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainScreenActivity.this, "Decline", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if(radioRedirect.getVisibility() != View.GONE){
                            if (radioRedirect.isChecked()){
                                Toast.makeText(MainScreenActivity.this, "Redirect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Everything seems to be fine (in my humble opinion) but I don't know if there is something wrong or missing or I can't just use `Dialog` this way. If this is right approach it would be great for me, because i could replace all `Dialog`s I have used before with my custom versions and that would make app a bit nicer, and clear.

Comment: it might be problem due to constraint Layout

Comment: if(!isCoordinator) redirect.setVisibility(View.GONE);  What is this? Think its could cause your issue. Use View.INVISIBLE. than it wil not hide other views

Comment: it should hide only one `RadioButton` if I leave it invisible there will be empty space left between `RadioButton` and `Button`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use `DialogFragment` for this.

`DialogCreator.java`

```
public class DialogCreator extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String TASK_ID_KEY = "taskID";
    private static final String COORDINATOR_KEY = "isCoordinator";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setCancelable(false);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle);
    }

    public static DialogCreator newInstance(String taskID, boolean isCoordinator) {
        DialogCreator creator = new DialogCreator();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(TASK_ID_KEY, taskID);
        bundle.putBoolean(COORDINATOR_KEY, isCoordinator);
        creator.setArguments(bundle);
        return creator;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        TextView task = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView chooseOptionText = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Button cancelButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button okButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final RadioButton radioAccept = view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        final RadioButton radioDecline = view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

        final RadioButton redirect = view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle == null) return;
        if (!bundle.containsKey(TASK_ID_KEY) || !bundle.containsKey(COORDINATOR_KEY)) return;

        boolean isCoordinator = bundle.getBoolean(COORDINATOR_KEY);
        String taskID = bundle.getString(TASK_ID_KEY);
        if (!isCoordinator) redirect.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        task.setText("ID: " + taskID);
        chooseOptionText.setText("Choose option:");
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (radioAccept.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (radioDecline.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Decline", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (redirect.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                    if (redirect.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Redirect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

FullScreenDialogStyle in your styles.xml

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

In your activity:

```
DialogCreator.newInstance("taskID",true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"TAG")
```

Comment: I thought I can make one `Class` to manage various Dialogs, but it looks like this one can do it with just one, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @SkypeDogg Yeah, you can create a base class `BaseDialogFragment` or use this one as base and then use it to create other dialogs with personalised configurations. It reduces boilerplate of setting styles and flags each time.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but one more thing: functionality inside onClick method isn't just Toast or anything that I can do inside this class. It is outside and I need to "inject" this dialog to cooperate with existing code. The best way for me was to put `OnClickListener` as a parameter, but it gives me `NullPointerException`. Do you know maybe some workarround?

Answer (score 0):

try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342157/7507788) answer to understand how to create a dialog with a custom layout. You're using the function `showSwitchDialog` to create the dialog, but I think you should create the dialog from a class extending the `Dialog` class and then show it with something like:

```
CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass();
cdd.show();
```

from the link above.
I tried to rewrite your layout file using a `LinearLayout` root tag, that may be the problem in showing the other views. If it doesn't solve the problem try to adjust the creation of the dialog as it shows in the above answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_site_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@color/burgrundy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:text="Akceptuj"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:text="Odrzuć"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:text="Przekaż dalej"
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@color/igloo_theme_color"
            android:text="Anuluj"
            android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/igloo_theme_color"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it works!